# JavaScript: Can you add images to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, ionic-framework

I have an array, and each item within the array contains a title and a description, I would also like to add an image to each item as well. How can I do this?

```
var myArray = [
    {title: "my title", description: "my description."},
    {title: "my title", description: "my description."},
    {title: "my title", description: "my description."},
];
```

I've already tried `{title: "my title", description: "my description.", image: src="my file path here"},` but that didn't work for me.

Comment: `{title: "my title", description: "my description.", imagesrc="my file path here"}`

Comment: Is like @shakib said. You see, you can't add `src=` on a javascript object.

Comment: Do you need image object or just file path string?

Comment: an alternate to @shakib 's comment would be to make the image point to another object with image property `{image: { src : "my file path here" }}`

Comment: Hm I've tried all of these now, but it just outputs the file path not the actual image.

Answer (score 1):

Of course? Just add *actual image elements* =)

```
var myArray = [{
  title: "my title",
  description: "my description.",
  image: buildImage("http://example.org/thing.png");
}, {
  title: ...
  ...
});
```

With a simple builder function like:

```
function buildImage(url) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onerror = function() {
    console.log("could not load image on URL " + url);
  };
  img.src = url;
  return img;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it's outputting [objectHTMLImageElement] rather than the image itself.

Comment: yes, of course. What do you think an image is in the browser? Because the thing you're showing in your comment is the correct thing, that is what an image is =) So: did you want the binary data of the image instead? Because that's also possible, but you can't really use that data for anything, unless you left off a LOT of details in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I'm pretty confused, I don't know much JavaScript at all. Basically I have an array which I am randomizing through when I press a button in the browser. Each array item has a title & description. I also want to add an image to each array item, and I want that image to be displayed in the browser right next to the title and description. I don't want to collect any data or anything of the sort, I simply want to hard code an image into each array item and have the image display in the browser.

Comment: right, so you if you need that image in your html, you simply [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) it to the thing you're putting your title and description in, too.